# 500 error with knockout delete

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am getting a 500 error when I try and delete an item in my list using ajax.

From using the console on Chrome combined with Fiddler, a null reference on the Id is the  issue. Debugging through Chrome's console shows that the announcement object does have an Id.

I was under the impression 500 errors came from the server, but I have a break point on the function path it's calling and not getting hit.

Is there anything that is staring me in the face as to why this would be setting the announcement.Id to null?

**controller:**

```
public JsonResult DeleteAnnouncement(int Id)
        {
            if(repository.DeleteAnnouncement(Id))
            {
                return Json(repository.GetAllAnnouncements(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            return Json(null);
        }
```

**repository:**

```
public bool DeleteAnnouncement(int Id)
        {
            var model = (from a in db.DbAnnouncement
                                     where a.Id == Id
                                     select a).SingleOrDefault();
            if (model.Id != 0)
            {
                db.DbAnnouncement.Remove(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**js script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function AnnouncementViewModel() {
            //Make the self as 'this' reference
            var self = this;
            //Declare observable which will be bind with UI
            self.Id = ko.observable("");
            self.Title = ko.observable("");
            self.Details = ko.observable("");
            self.DTCreated = ko.observable("");
            self.LastUpdated = ko.observable("");
            self.CreatedUser = ko.observable("");
            self.UpdatedUser = ko.observable("");
            self.VersionNum = ko.observable("");
            self.StartDT = ko.observable("");
            self.ExpiryDT = ko.observable("");
            self.Enabled = ko.observable("");
            self.GroupID = ko.observable("");
            self.URLLink = ko.observable("");

            var Announcement = {
                Id: self.Id,
                Title: self.Title,
                Details: self.Details,
                DTCreated: self.DTCreated,
                LastUpdated: self.LastUpdated,
                CreatedUser: self.CreatedUser,
                UpdatedUser: self.UpdatedUser,
                VersionNum: self.VersionNum,
                StartDT: self.StartDT,
                ExpiryDT: self.ExpiryDT,
                Enabled: self.Enabled,
                GroupID: self.GroupID,
                URLLink: self.URLLink
            };

            self.Announcement = ko.observable();
            self.Announcements = ko.observableArray(); // list of announcements

            // Delete announcement
            self.delete = function (Announcement) {
                if (confirm('Are you sure to Delete "' + Announcement.Title + '"?')) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("DeleteAnnouncement","Announcement")',
                        cache: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        //data: ko.toJSON(Announcement.Id),
                        data: {Id: Announcement.Id},
                        success: function (data) {
                            self.Announcements.remove(Announcement);
                            alert("Record Deleted Successfully");
                        }
                    }).fail(
                    function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                        alert(err);
                    });
                }
            }


        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var viewModel = new AnnouncementViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ajax `contentType` as Json but not really sending a json object to server. Use

```
data: JSON.stringify({ Id: Announcement.Id() }),
```

and decorate your mvc action with `[HttpPost]`

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteAnnouncement(int Id)
{}
```

Comment: Sorry, was away from desk. Yes, stringify is better than mine solved it using `data: '{"Id":"' + Announcement.Id + '"}',` Thanks for the explanation! =)